What is the technique of dropping the knee in cricket called?
You see it often in cricket. A fielder will drop the knee when fielding. The idea being if the ball goes through your hands your leg is still there to stop the ball.
Who came up with that technique and what is it called?

This is the long barrier technique. I suspect the history of it is lost to time.

Could we get you add the content of that link? Link rot can happen.
